# batch file only executes first command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to automate some scripts, but i don't know much about batch files. Can anyone tell me, why only the first command is being executed? I know the 2nd one works too, since i can run it if i delete the first line.

I have Windows 10 and this is my .cmd file:

```
npm run build
WinSCP.exe /console /script=./script.txt
pause
```

Comment: If `npm` is a .bat or .cmd script, then use `CALL npm run build`

Comment: as stated by @lit `call npm run build` because it is a `batch-file`. but additionally, `start "" WinSCP.exe..`